# Eclipselink class extractor

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, extractor

I have 2 entities object A and B. B extended A and I have `@ClassExtractor` on A to return the correct class type from the database row. However, if I want to query on A, will it check for class extractor?

A.java

```
@Entity
@Table
@ClassExtractor(MyClassExtractor.class)
public class A implements Serializable{
...
}
```

B.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class A extends B{
...
}
```

MyClassExtractor.java

```
public class MyClassExtractor extends ClassExtractor{
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public Class extractClassFromRow(Record record, Session session){
return B.class;
}
```

So when I do query on A, will it go to the class extractor and return B? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: will "what" check for ClassExtractor? Since that is not part of the JPA spec you can be safe in knowing that a JPA implementation won't see it

Comment: @NeilStockton if I do query on A, will A go to `MyClassExtractor`and return B? since it annotated with @ClassExtractor

Comment: If you do a query on A, a JPA provider will instantiate instances of A, because that is what the query is for. A JPA PROVIDER has NOTHING to do with whatever this ClassExtractor annotation is. Searching shows that this annotation is from ECLIPSELINK. So if you want to ask about ECLIPSELINK why not mention it in the question? Any other JPA provider will totally ignore it. EclipseLink API != JPA API

Comment: according to JPA documentation, "Use @ClassExtractor to define a custom class indicator in place of providing a discriminator column." I'm using class extractor annotation to query on extended entity because my table do not have a discriminator column.

Comment: No that is NOT "JPA DOCUMENTATION". It is ECLIPSELINK DOCUMENTATION. EclipseLink API != JPA API. Read the JPA spec and you will find no mention of it! Your ClassExtractor has a package name of "org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors" which really ought to be a clue for you ... ECLIPSELINK, and not javax.persistence (JPA)

Comment: As Neil is pointing out, you should be looking at the EclipseLink documentation, http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_classextractor.htm  There you will see an example with the ClassExtractor annotation.  It will run when querying for the root class if it also specifies the "Inheritance" annotation which your code doesn't show.

Comment: Yeah i figured out by putting a logger in my class extractor. Thanks tho!